# i create a discord level bot but it get error say not defined

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I create a discord level bot, but when i use `$rank` it get a err say `get_point` is not defined
cab some one help me?

```python
import discord,time,json
from discord.ext import commands
class Lvl(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self,bot):
        self.bot = bot
    
    try:
        with open("users.json") as fp:
            users = json.load(fp)
    except Exception:
        users = {}

    def save_users():
        with open("users.json", "w+") as fp:
            json.dump(users, fp, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

    def add_points(user: discord.User, points: int):
        id = user.id
        if id not in users:
            users[id] = {}
        users[id]["points"] = users[id].get("points", 0) + points
        save_users()

    def get_points(user: discord.User):
        id = user.id
        if id in users:
            return users[id].get("points", 0)
        return 0

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self , message):
        if message.author == self.bot.user:
            return
        add_points(message.author, 1)
        
    @commands.command()
    async def rank(ctx,self):
        await ctx.send(f"you have {get_points(message.author)} point")
        

    def setup(bot):
        bot.add_cog(Lvl(bot))
```

Comment: You have to decide which of these are class methods and which are functions that are not part of the class.  Class members have a "self" parameter FIRST and are indented.  Functions do not have a "self" parameter and are not indented.  You can't mix them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is in a class so use self while defining

```
    def get_points(self, user: discord.User):
    id = user.id
    if id in users:
        return users[id].get("points", 0)
    return 0
```

and while calling get points you need to use self too

```
@commands.command()
async def rank(self, ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"you have {self.get_points(message.author)} point")
```